# C++, OpenCV: run cuda::dft asynchronously

Tags: c++, opencv

I noticed that the function `cv::cuda::dft` of OpenCV runs synchronously also if a stream is passed. Usually this implies that the function is executed asynchronously. However, as it seems the dft function invokes `cudaFree` which causes synchronous behaviour.

Is there a way to make it run asynchronously?

Comment: You can see for yourself that within dft there are no explicit calls to cudaFree : https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/cudaarithm/src/arithm.cpp#L291

Comment: But as soon as I call dft the Nvidia Profiler shows me cudaFree calls that weren't there before and everything starts becoming synchronous.

Comment: From what I see it looks as if under certain circumstances there are new GpuMats created in that function. In that case they will be freed at the end of the scope.

Comment: Exactly as I said on your last question about this. So work out if you use case will trigger those code paths and modify your code accordingly to avoid them. Or write your own dft implementation which avoids touching memory allocation or deallocation within the function. I don't see a CUDA programming question here, so unless you can provide a compelling reason, I will remove the tag from this question.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem. `cv::cuda::dft` was creating and destroying a plan every time it was called. This caused the calls of `cudaFree` and `cudaMalloc`. Doing it manually with cufft and only creating a plan once before the loop solved the problem. I wonder why they didn't use the same scheme as with the cudafilters where you first create the filter and then are able to call it with different input and output data multiple times.

Comment: If you want to write a very short answer summarising what you found, I will happily upvote this to get the question off the unanswered queue (its perfectly OK to answer your own question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies within the creation and destruction of cufft plans. The function `cv::cuda::dft` does this every time you call it. This is quite inefficient when done in a loop and causes synchronous calls. At the moment it seems that there is no way to create a dft filter and then apply it multiple times, as it is possible with cudafilters where you can first create a filter and then apply it multiple times on different data.

In the end I solved this by not using OpenCV's dft function but directly cufft instead. I could then create a plan once before the loop, do my ffts with that one plan inside the loop and then destroy it after the loop.